# Why does the glTF schema define enums like this?

Tags: json, enums, jsonschema, gltf

If I search for "enum" in the glTF 2.0 schema, I see a lot of definitions of enums like:

```
        "type": {
            "description": "Specifies if the camera uses a perspective or orthographic projection.",
            "gltf_detailedDescription": "Specifies if the camera uses a perspective or orthographic projection.  Based on this, either the camera's `perspective` or `orthographic` property will be defined.",
            "anyOf": [
                {
                    "enum": [ "perspective" ]
                },
                {
                    "enum": [ "orthographic" ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ]
        },
```

(from the [camera schema](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/27988cbe931308c7b57bdfae3e4ca9e1a34292e1/specification/2.0/schema/camera.schema.json))

I have several questions about this:

1. I don't understand why this is anyOf instead of oneOf? My understanding is that a camera type is EITHER perspective or orthographic, and my understanding of json schema is that ['anyOf' allows validation against multiple values in the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34038183/what-is-the-difference-between-anyof-and-oneof-in-z-schema)).
2. I don't understand the "type":"string" field? To me that reads as though any string value would be valid? This seems inconsistent with the camera definition of glTF?

There are multiple instances of enums like this. see also: 
[here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/27988cbe931308c7b57bdfae3e4ca9e1a34292e1/specification/2.0/schema/animation.sampler.schema.json) [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/b1d5f74e27ef1244eed8950e9e179bd74ee58ba2/extensions/2.0/Vendor/AGI_articulations/schema/articulation.stage.schema.json)

Thanks in advance for any clarity someone can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time (2017) we were using JSON schema draft v4, and support for enums was not up to where we needed it to be.  Previously there had been a simple list of enums, but I requested there to be per-enum descriptions in the schema.  This better documents the individual enum values in the schema, and allows formatting software to display the description of an individual enum value.  I filed an issue on that here:

https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/issues/891

Further down that issue, a problem was uncovered with `oneOf` that made it incompatible with TypeScript, and a decision was made to switch to `anyOf` instead.  You can still only choose one of the available enums, in spite of this change.

Later, in the Pull Request that implemented this change, one of the spec editors [explained](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/pull/899#discussion_r110480173) that the extra `"type" : "string"` on the end there is to allow future forwards-compatibility.  Basically this means that glTF 2.0 extensions are allowed (and encouraged) to define new enum values that don't exist in core glTF 2.0 schema, and they may do so without violating the schema.  They cannot arbitrarily add new fields, however, as the schema is strict about that.  New fields must be placed into an `extension` or `extras` object of the appropriate name.  But new enums can go right in the same field where the existing enums are now.

Ultimately, we ended up with a schema that may be a little cumbersome for humans to look at, but works well in a wide variety of validation software that deals with JSON schemas.  And the humans can just look at the [Properties Reference README](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/specification/2.0#properties-reference) instead of the raw schema files, it's easier on the eyes.